# Multi-thread program in C - takes longer to run than single thread

Tags: c, multithreading

In my program I'm calculating the min value in an array. I do this with no threads and with threads. However, I noticed that as I increase the number of threads the program takes longer to run (I'm using timeval to calculate this). This doesn't make much sense to me and this is also my first time trying to program with threads. Any ideas on what is causing this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

struct timeval start_time, stop_time;

#define N_items 100;

int num_threads = 1;

int start[100];
int x[4000];
int min[100];
pthread_t tid[100];

void *thread(void *arg)
{
    int i, s;
    double my_min;

    s = *(int *) arg;

    my_min = x[s];
    for(i=s+num_threads; i<4000; i+= num_threads){
        if(x[i]<my_min)
            my_min = x[i];
    }

    min[s] = my_min;
    return NULL;

}




int main(){
    int i;
    int my_min;
    int elapsed;

    //Create array of size 4000 with random numbers
    for (i=0; i<4000; i++){
        x[i] = random()%100+1;  
    }


    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

    //Create threads
    for(i = 0; i<num_threads; i++){
        start[i] = i;
        if ( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread, (void *)&start[i]) ) {
            printf("Can't create thread\n");
        }

    }

    for(i = 0; i<num_threads; i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }


    my_min = min[0];
    for(i = 0; i<num_threads; i++) {
        if(min[i]<my_min)
            my_min = min[i];
    }

    gettimeofday(&stop_time, NULL);

    printf("min is: %d\n", my_min);

    elapsed = (stop_time.tv_sec*1000000+ stop_time.tv_usec) -
              (start_time.tv_sec*1000000+ start_time.tv_usec);

    printf("Elapsed time is: %d\n", elapsed );

}
```

Comment: What does your "no thread" program look like? Is it just what you have shown with `num_threads=1`? Also, what value(s) of `num_thread` are you using and what are the resulting times versus the "no thread" test?

Comment: The no thread program is simply two for loops, one to create the array, the second to calculate the min. I'm getting around 100 microsec for the no thread program and about 190 microsec for a 4 thread program.

Comment: Change 4000 to 4000000.  Try again.

Comment: There could be a couple of main reasons. 1. The threaded version is counting all the `pthread_join` calls as well as the time to gather the results from all the threads. This doesn't need to be done for the non-threaded program. 2. Creating and switching threads is not free. So that overhead can outweigh the savings (not saying that's for sure in this case but it does need to be considered).

Comment: kaylum - I think this is true. After playing with larger numbers I found a value that produces faster time with threads. Thank you.

Comment: Threads are mainly for parallelism. But we need to keep in mind that threads creates  little bit overhead because of context switching on aspect of processor. For small range of numbers you might not identify the difference properly. Please increase your input and increase the thread numbers also.  As parent process is waiting for pthread join, so it also including some extra overhead.

Comment: did you replace `int num_threads = 1;` with `const int num_threads = 5;` (and of course 4000 with 400000000) ? BTW you are lacking the *pthread* tag, and probably the *Linux* or *POSIX* one. You really should edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I just thought to add a tip to this: If you need to use threads to process large amounts of data in loops, learn to use OpenMP. It is built into GCC and clang and makes parallel programming so much easier. See http://openmp.org/

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in creating and destroying a thread just to do 4,000 quick operations. You're measuring overhead, not work.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you are doing wrong is that `i += num_threads`. Using CPU cache effectively is very important and what you are doing there is wasting it.

You want to use solid sequential access blocks instead of jumping all over the place. Maybe try (untested):

```
int count = 4000;
int chunk = count / num_threads;
int start = s * chunk;
int end = start + chunk;
for(int i = start; i < end; ++i)
```